# How to use retryWhen with a function that returns a Boolean?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5, angular2-observables

Here's my code:

```
this._http.post(this._url_get + extension, '', { headers: headers })
    .map(res => res['_body'])
    .retryWhen(errors => {return responseErrorProcess(errors)})
```

now I need to catch exceptions and pass them to my `responseErrorProcess()` which returns `true` if it needs to retry

I could not figure out how to retrieve the exceptions from `errors`, this is how it looks:

```
Subject_isScalar: falseclosed: falsehasError: falseisStopped: falseobservers: Array[0]thrownError: null__proto__: Observable`
```

It doesn't seem to contain errors about the exceptions that occurs, plus I couldn't figure out what should I return in order to actually retry or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`retryWhen` should return an Observable. The retry occurs once that observable emits:

```
.retryWhen(errors => 
    //switchMap to retrieve the source error
    errors.switchMap(sourceErr => 
        //send source to processor
        responseErrorsProcess(sourceErr) ? 
        //if result is TRUE, emit (will cause retry). Else, pass on the error
        Observable.of(true): Observable.throw(sourceErr)
    )
)
```

If you want to complete instead of error when your processor returns `false`, replace `Observable.throw()` with `Observable.empty()`

Answer (score 6):

The callable to [`retryWhen()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen) needs to return an Observable that emits `complete` or `error` to end the stream or emits a value to resubscribe.

For example this code completes without emitting the error because of `Observable.empty()`:

```
Observable.create(obs => {
    obs.next(1);
    obs.next(2);
    obs.error('error from source');
  })
  .retryWhen((errors) => {
      errors.subscribe(sourceError => console.log(sourceError));
      return Observable.create(obs => obs.error('inner error'));
  })
  .subscribe(
    val => console.log(val),
    err => console.log('error', err),
    _ => console.log('complete')
  );
```

The error from source Observable is emitted to `errors` as `next`. See source code: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/operator/retryWhen.ts#L86

This prints to console:

```
1
2
error inner error
error from source
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Fajsb54WJwB8J8hkUC6j?p=preview

**Edit based on comments bellow:**

Look at the documentation for `retryWhen()`:

> An error will cause the emission of the Throwable that cause **the error to the Observable returned from notificationHandler**. If that Observable calls **onComplete or error** then retry will call complete or error on the child subscription. **Otherwise, this Observable will resubscribe to the source observable**, on a particular Scheduler.

So the Observable returned from the callback is responsible to decide whether to resubscribe. If it emits `next()`, then resubscribe. If it emits `error()` or `complete()` pass those to the child Observer.

For example you could do (I didn't test this code):

```
return response.retryWhen((errors) => {
    var retrySource = new Subject();
    errors.subscribe(error => {
        if (this.responseErrorProcess(error)) retrySource.next();
        else retrySource.complete();
    });
    return retrySource;
});
```

According to your inner logic you trigger the correct message on `retrySource`.

Comment: thank you! but how to get the errors? u see, the error that we get like this is an observable and does not actually contain the exception, not the same error that I would get with .catch() which actually contains the http response (sorry for my weak way of explanating)

Comment: @MotassemMK See my updated answer. It works exactly as it's documented in http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retryWhen. However, I agree the description is very often super confusing.

Comment: well excellent I got the errors! but, (and sorry its the 2nd follow up question) how can I return a value to retryWhen from inside the flatMap as its async? this is what I tried:

Comment: `return response
  .retryWhen((errors) => {
   var retrySource
   errors.flatMap(error => { if (this.responseErrorProcess(error)) return retrySource = error; else return retrySource = Observable.empty() })
   return retrySource
  })`

Comment: but of course its not working as `retryWhen` won't wait till the flatMap finishes, so im able to get the errors, and able to stop/retry the subscription, but not both of them

Comment: @MotassemMK I updated my answer, look at the bottom.

Comment: I guess you meant a `BehaviorSubject`, won't work like this, you need to subscribe to it to get the changes you sent through next() or complete(), I'm getting the same result for both

Comment: this is the code I used (few fixes to yours): `.retryWhen((errors) => {
    var retrySource = new BehaviorSubject<any>(1)
    errors.flatMap(error => {
     if (this.responseErrorProcess(error)) retrySource.next(1)
     else retrySource.complete()
     return error
    })
    console.log(retrySource)
    return retrySource
   })`

Comment: @MotassemMK You're right, use `subscribe()` instead of `flatMap `

Comment: thanks a lot !! you clarified it all, @BeetleJuice provided a working code that solved it like charm, thank for both of you :)