# Error response break valueChanges [Angular2]

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

When I subscirbe to form and wait for value changes that break if I resonse is error from my service...

Here is code:

```
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private bankService: BankService) {
        this.page = 1;

        this.filter = this.fb.group({
            text: ['', []],
            bankC: ['', []]
        });

        this.filter.valueChanges
            // wait for a pause in typing of 200ms then emit the last value
            .debounceTime(200)
            // only accept values that don't repeat themselves
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            // map that to an observable HTTP request, using the TickerLoad
            // service and switch to that
            // observable. That means unsubscribing from any previous HTTP request
            // (cancelling it), and subscribing to the newly returned on here.
            .switchMap((val: any) => {
                return bankService.getCountry(val.bankC)
            })
            .subscribe((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            },
             (err) => {
                 console.log(err);
             });
            // send an empty array to tickers whenever clear emits by
            // merging in a the stream of clear events mapped to an
            // empty array.
    }
```

**Edit**

I found what couse problem, it is inside http intreceptor:

```
intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
        return observable.catch((err, source) => {
            if (err.status == 401) {
                this._router.navigate(['']);
                return Observable.throw(err);
                //&& !_.endsWith(err.url, 'api/auth/login')
            } else {
               return Observable.throw(err);
            }
        });

    }
```

It is this part: `return Observable.throw(err);`

How can I return error without braking subscription.

Comment: What error and how it breaks?

Comment: Server return 404 error and after that this: `this.filter.valueChanges` not working. It just stop `console.log`

Comment: Does the error reach `console.log(err);`?

Comment: Yes... standar message from server: `Response {_body: "{"message":"Not found."}", status: 404, ok: false, statusText: "Not Found", headers: Headers…}`

Comment: Do you have a `.catch` after the `.map` in `getCountry()`?

Comment: I don't have but I have it in intreceptor... Interceptor return `return Observable.throw(err);` . When I remove that part it works ok but I get ugly error message in console... Any way to fix it?

Comment: The only purpose of `Observable.throw(err);` is to throw an error message. So if you remove it, it doesn't throw anything. However the `catch()` operator then doesn't receive any Observable to continue.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resubscribe to the source Observable use [`retry()` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry) before `subscribe()`:

```
...
.switchMap((val: any) => {
    return bankService.getCountry(val.bankC)
})
.retry(-1) // resubscribe forever
.subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
}, ...
```

Comment: I would rather prefer not to use ultimate reset... I found what couse problem could you check edit in main post?

Comment: @VladimirDjukic You can't return error without breaking unsubscribing. That's RxJS behavior by design. You can however reconnect using `retry()` or `retryWhen()` operators or switch to another Observable using `catch()` operator.

Comment: If I `retry(-1)` It will send a lot of request to server... It would be good if I can in intreceptor on 404 error to continue response but to send error data...

Comment: @VladimirDjukic Yes, `retry(-1)` resubscribes endlessly. You can of course use `retry(1)` to resubscribe just once or use `retryWhen(error => /* new Observable */)`that's able to decide if and when you want to resubscribe. See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184509/how-to-use-retrywhen-with-a-function-that-returns-a-boolean/40193878#40193878

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but try using -

```
return throwError(err);
```

Or you can also throw a recovery observable.

```
return of(null);
```

Or

```
return EMPTY;
```

You can also use RxJs pipe operator to chain multiple catchError operators like this -

```
.pipe(
    catchError((err) => throwError(err)),
    catchError((err) => of([])
);
```

One to throw a recovery error observable and other one to send a recovery empty Observable. This way you can display error message to user and send a recovery Observable to subscribe to. This will never break the chain.